# Debugging on iOS 4.3 simulator

Tags: iphone, xcode

I've been developing everything with the Xcode 4.2 on leopard, I recently installed Lion, the Lion version of Xcode 4.2, and everything turned into 5.0! The simulator, my project, everything.

Now I tried to make my project deployment target 4.3 and changed the simulator, and all I get is a black screen when my application starts, I don't even hit breakpoints on viewDidLoad.

Comment: Good question, but if it were my question I'd change the title to something a bit more descriptive like "non-running app in simulator?" or "why only black screen when launching in simulator?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had this frustrating problem before (black screen after launching the app in the simulator and no breakpoints hitting and no indication anything was happening in the Debugging console).

I sense it was a corrupted XIB file somewhere between the build products and the simulator.

Now I'm not 100% certain what fixed it for me, but I did a combination of "cleaning" the project (and even throwing away the Derived Data folder) and also deleting the app from the simulator, then restarting both Xcode and the simulator before rebuilding the app.